# WHERE xxx NOT IN... not returning anything

Tags: sql-server-2008

Can someone please explain why the last statement does not list all the ST items which ARE in #inv_item but not in salesMasterDET? I’m using SQL 2008 R2

IF I populate a temp table with:
SELECT DISTINCT(productCode) INTO #smd_item  FROM salesMasterDET
And I run the same selects, S1-S4 but with the temp table, everything works fine.

S1: SELECT DISTINCT(Item) FROM #inv_item

S2: SELECT DISTINCT(ProductCode) FROM salesMasterDET

S3: SELECT DISTINCT(Item) FROM #inv_item where Item IN (SELECT ProductCode FROM salesMasterDET)

S4: SELECT DISTINCT(Item) FROM #inv_item where Item NOT IN (SELECT ProductCode FROM salesMasterDET)

RESULTS:

S1: ST01 ST02 ST03 ST04 ST05 ST11 ST12

S2: ST04 ST12

S3: ST04 ST12

S4: **(no results) (expecting ST01, ST 02, , , ST11)**

Comment: If you run the query `SELECT * FROM salesMasterDET WHERE ProductCode IS NULL` does it return any results? If so, that is the problem. No value compared to `NULL` will return from the `NOT IN`. You can change the query to `SELECT DISTINCT(Item) FROM #inv_item where Item NOT IN (SELECT ProductCode FROM salesMasterDET WHERE ProductCode IS NOT NULL)`

Comment: I usually remove nulls from these tables and didn't think about that end of it, but there were nulls. Problem solved. Simple answer and reason. Thanks Adriaan.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you should reverse the binary operation.

```
S4: SELECT DISTINCT(Item) FROM #inv_item where NOT Item IN (SELECT ProductCode FROM salesMasterDET)
```